# Accessing elements of Oracle PLSQL record type on runtime

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am using dynamic SQL where I am dynamically using value of column name to bind  and its value to be bind

OLD CODE

```
<Outer Loop>
FOR i IN lvaDBOBJDTLRecTab.FIRST .. lvaDBOBJDTLRecTab.LAST
LOOP
  DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE ( lvnInsertCursorId, ':RTTEXT2VC100', 
  lvaDBOBJDTLRecTab(i).DBONAME  );

  DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE ( lvnInsertCursorId, ':RTTEXT3VC100', 
  lvaDBOBJDTLRecTab(i).DBOTYPE  );
    3.
   .
  .
  .
  100

END LOOP;
```

Instead of writing BIND_VARIABLE for 100 times , I want to dynamically access value of collection. I am able to fetch the value of columns dynamically, which need to be bind (lvsColForBinding), however value of lvsColValForBind
is coming as 'lvrCurDBOBJDTL(i).DBONAME' , 'lvrCurDBOBJDTL(i).DBOTYPE' 
and same for rest of the 98 columns,

```
       <Inner Loop>
    FOR j IN lvaMappingTab.FIRST..lvaMappingTab.LAST
    LOOP
    lvsColForBinding := ':'||lvaMappingTab(j).MstRptColCds;

        lvsColValForBind :=  'lvrCurDBOBJDTL(i).'||lvaMappingTab(j).RptColCd;

DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE ( lvnInsertCursorId,lvsColForBinding, lvsColValForBind);

  END LOOP;
```

when DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE is run for each row, as mentioned earlier Column to be bind comes correct but value to be bind, instead of coming as 
value of 'XYZ' = lvrCurDBOBJDTL(i).DBONAME it comes as this in single quotes 'lvrCurDBOBJDTL(i).DBONAME' same for all columns.
how can we extract the value of each element in inner loop. what step we need to do to fetch the value of lvsColValForBind?

While debugging through SQLDEveloper Watches, I can see the, element name, value and type, when adding and double clicking the plsql record variable,
what is the SQL behind that, can we use that in coding ?

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation is that you use dynamic SQL to generate lots of dumb code instead of using a small amount of smart PL/SQL.  If code generation doesn't work, you can use ANYDATA and ANYTYPE to create PL/SQL reflection to dynamically iterate through the elements of a record at run time.

### Code Generation

Don't *write* BIND_VARIABLE 100 times, but create a small program to *generate* the 100 lines of code for you.  If the data is ultimately coming from one table and going into another table, the input and output may be predictable based on data dictionary views like DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.

Hopefully a small query like this could help generate all the code for a single table:

```
--Generate PL/SQL statements for binds.
select
    'DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(lvnInsertCursorId, '':RTTEXT'||column_id||'VC100'', lvaDBOBJDTLRecTab(i).'||column_name||');'
from dba_tab_columns
where owner = 'SOME_OWNER'
    and table_name = 'SOME_TABLE'
order by 1;
```

Then you can copy-and-paste the output into the PL/SQL block.  You'll probably also want a warning, like "do not modify, this code is autogenerated by the procedure CODE_TRON_2000".

This approach will only work if the PL/SQL code is predictable, based on the data dictionary or some other metadata.

### PL/SQL Reflection

There's no pure PL/SQL reflection for PL/SQL types* but there's a simple workaround if you're willing to create the record types as SQL objects instead.  If all your PL/SQL records are based on object types then ANYDATA and ANYTYPE can be used to dynamically access attributes.  Object types and PL/SQL record types are pretty similar, it should be relatively painless to convert one to the other.

For example, if you create an object type that contains a number and a string:

```
create or replace type v_type is object(a number, b varchar2(1));
```

This (painful) PL/SQL block shows how to iterate through all the records of a collection, and then iterate through all of the attributes in each record.  (The code prints the values for, you'll have to add the binding parts yourself.)

```
declare
    type v_nt_type is table of v_type;
    v_values v_nt_type := v_nt_type(v_type(1, 'A'), v_type(2, 'B'));
begin
    --For each record:
    for i in 1 .. v_values.count loop
        declare
            v_anydata anydata := anydata.ConvertObject(v_values(i));
            v_number number;
            v_varchar2 varchar2(4000);
            v_result pls_integer;
            v_anytype anytype;
            v_dummy_num  pls_integer;
            v_dummy_char varchar2(4000);
            v_dummy_anytype anytype;
            v_number_of_elements number;
        begin
            --Get the ANYTYPE and the number of elements.
            v_result := v_anydata.getType(v_anytype);
            v_result := v_anytype.getInfo
            (
               prec        => v_dummy_num,
               scale       => v_dummy_num,
               len         => v_dummy_num,
               csid        => v_dummy_num,
               csfrm       => v_dummy_num,
               schema_name => v_dummy_char,
               type_name   => v_dummy_char,
               version     => v_dummy_char,
               numelems    => v_number_of_elements
            );

            --For each element in the record:
            for i in 1 .. v_number_of_elements loop
                --Find the type of the element:
                v_anydata.piecewise;
                v_result := v_anytype.getAttrElemInfo(
                pos            => i,
                prec           => v_dummy_num,
                scale          => v_dummy_num,
                len            => v_dummy_num,
                csid           => v_dummy_num,
                csfrm          => v_dummy_num,
                attr_elt_type  => v_dummy_anytype,
                aname          => v_dummy_char);

                --This is where you do something interesting with the values.
                --(The same code merely prints the values.)
                if v_result = dbms_types.typecode_number then
                    v_result := v_anydata.getNumber(num => v_number);
                    dbms_output.put_line(v_number);
                elsif v_result = dbms_types.typecode_varchar2 then
                    v_result := v_anydata.getVarchar2(c => v_varchar2);
                    dbms_output.put_line(v_varchar2);
                --TODO: Add other potential types here.
                end if;
            end loop;
        end;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Results:

```
1
A
2
B
```

* You're right that there must be *some* way to find this run time information, if the debugger gets it.  But as far as I know there is no way for PL/SQL to retrieve that debug information.  Maybe it's only available to an OCI(?) interface?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `bind_variable`, you are binding an actual value to a placeholder. So if you provide a string that is the name of your variable, well, that string is the value bound to the placeholder.

If the array holds those values, then simply reference the array element and not the name of that element, as in:

```
DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE ( 
   lvnInsertCursorId,
   lvaMappingTab(j).MstRptColCds, 
   lvrCurDBOBJDTL(i).lvaMappingTab(j).RptColCd);
```

But I am pretty sure that's not what you've got there. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried that also, it gives an error : PLS-00302: Component 'lvaMappingTab' must be declared.
As a next step, I have declared 'lvaMappingTab' at package level. Same error PLS-00302. 
That’s the reason I was trying to use feature/ SQL which is used by SQLDEVELOPER while generating value of collection elements inside “WATCHES” window. it shows name of the element, value of the element and type of the element (+more details) Similar to that, If I can access the elements dynamically, I should be able to compare and match the bind variable values.

Answer (score 0):

@Jon
Thanks for your inputs, that helped. also I am able to iterate cols without creating OBJECTs using DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS.

**Below code still need little bit fine tuning, but mostly working :)

```
   BEGIN
        COLS_TRAVERSE('SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE ROWNUM<=100');
   END;



   create or replace PROCEDURE COLS_TRAVERSE ( p_query in varchar2 )
   AS
            v_curid    NUMBER;
            v_desctab  DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
            v_colcnt   NUMBER;
            v_RowNumcnt   NUMBER := 1;
            v_Colname_var  VARCHAR2(10000);
            v_name_var  VARCHAR2(10000);
            v_num_var   NUMBER;
            v_date_var  DATE;
            v_row_num    NUMBER;
            p_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);

   BEGIN
        v_curid := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
        DBMS_SQL.PARSE(v_curid, p_query, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
        DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(v_curid, v_colcnt, v_desctab);

       -- Define columns:
       FOR i IN 1 .. v_colcnt LOOP
        IF v_desctab(i).col_type = 2 THEN
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(v_curid, i, v_num_var);
            ELSIF v_desctab(i).col_type = 12 THEN
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(v_curid, i, v_date_var);
            ELSE
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(v_curid, i, v_name_var, 50);
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        v_row_num := dbms_sql.execute(v_curid);
        -- Fetch rows with DBMS_SQL package:
        WHILE DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(v_curid) > 0 LOOP

          FOR i IN 1 .. v_colcnt 

            LOOP
                v_Colname_var := v_desctab(i).col_name;
                dbms_output.put_line( 'Name:' ||v_Colname_var );
                IF (v_desctab(i).col_type = 1) THEN
                    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(v_curid, i, v_name_var);
                    dbms_output.put_line( 'String Value:' || v_name_var );
                ELSIF (v_desctab(i).col_type = 2) THEN
                    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(v_curid, i, v_num_var);
                    dbms_output.put_line( 'Number Value:' || v_num_var);
                ELSIF (v_desctab(i).col_type = 12) THEN
                    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(v_curid, i, v_date_var);
                    dbms_output.put_line( 'Date Value:' || v_date_var );
                END IF;
            END LOOP;



            dbms_output.put_line( 'End of Row Number # ' ||v_RowNumcnt );

            v_RowNumcnt := v_RowNumcnt+1;

        END LOOP;

        DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(v_curid);
     END;
     /


    DBMS_OUT PUT 

    Name:OWNER
    String Value:SYS
    Name:OBJECT_NAME
    String Value:ORA$BASE
    Name:SUBOBJECT_NAME
    String Value:
    Name:OBJECT_ID
    Number Value:134
    Name:DATA_OBJECT_ID
    Number Value:
    Name:OBJECT_TYPE
    String Value:EDITION
    Name:CREATED
    Date Value:30-03-18
    Name:LAST_DDL_TIME
    Date Value:30-03-18
    Name:TIMESTAMP
    String Value:2018-03-30:21:37:22
    Name:STATUS
    String Value:VALID
    Name:TEMPORARY
    String Value:N
    Name:GENERATED
    String Value:N
    Name:SECONDARY
    String Value:N
    Name:NAMESPACE
    Number Value:64
    Name:EDITION_NAME
    String Value:
    Name:SHARING
    String Value:NONE
    Name:EDITIONABLE
    String Value:
    Name:ORACLE_MAINTAINED
    String Value:Y
    Name:APPLICATION
    String Value:N
    Name:DEFAULT_COLLATION
    String Value:
    Name:DUPLICATED
    String Value:N
    Name:SHARDED
    String Value:N
    Name:CREATED_APPID
    Number Value:
    Name:CREATED_VSNID
    Number Value:
    Name:MODIFIED_APPID
    Number Value:
    Name:MODIFIED_VSNID
    Number Value:
    End of Row Number # 1

    Name:OWNER
    String Value:SYS
    Name:OBJECT_NAME
    String Value:DUAL
    Name:SUBOBJECT_NAME
    String Value:
    Name:OBJECT_ID
    Number Value:143
    Name:DATA_OBJECT_ID
    Number Value:143
    Name:OBJECT_TYPE
    String Value:TABLE
    Name:CREATED
    Date Value:30-03-18
    Name:LAST_DDL_TIME
    Date Value:31-03-18
    Name:TIMESTAMP
    String Value:2018-03-30:21:37:22
    Name:STATUS
    String Value:VALID
    Name:TEMPORARY
    String Value:N
    Name:GENERATED
    String Value:N
    Name:SECONDARY
    String Value:N
    Name:NAMESPACE
    Number Value:1
    Name:EDITION_NAME
    String Value:
    Name:SHARING
    String Value:METADATA LINK
    Name:EDITIONABLE
    String Value:
    Name:ORACLE_MAINTAINED
    String Value:Y
    Name:APPLICATION
    String Value:N
    Name:DEFAULT_COLLATION
    String Value:USING_NLS_COMP
    Name:DUPLICATED
    String Value:N
    Name:SHARDED
    String Value:N
    Name:CREATED_APPID
    Number Value:
    Name:CREATED_VSNID
    Number Value:
    Name:MODIFIED_APPID
    Number Value:
    Name:MODIFIED_VSNID
    Number Value:
    End of Row Number # 2
```