# Dynamic Cursor Column Name

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to dynamically reference a cursor column name based off the value of another cursor. Example...

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT
        employee,
        employee_name
    FROM
        employee;

    CURSOR c2 IS
    SELECT
        my_column,
        my_column2
    FROM
        my_table;

BEGIN
    FOR r_c1 IN c1 LOOP
        FOR r_c2 IN c2 LOOP
                INSERT INTO test_table (test_column1,test_column2) values (r_c1.||r_c2.my_column, r_c1.||r_c2.my_column2)
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Is there a way to concatenate my r_c2 value onto the column name for r_c1? If not, is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing elements of Oracle PLSQL record type on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939727/accessing-elements-of-oracle-plsql-record-type-on-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression and white-list the values:

```sql
DECLARE
    CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT employee, employee_name
      FROM   employee;

    CURSOR c2 IS
      SELECT my_column, my_column2
      FROM   my_table;
BEGIN
  FOR r_c1 IN c1 LOOP
    FOR r_c2 IN c2 LOOP
      INSERT INTO test_table (
        test_column1,
        test_column2
      ) values (
        CASE r_c2.my_column
        WHEN 'EMPLOYEE'      THEN r_c1.employee
        WHEN 'EMPLOYEE_NAME' THEN r_c1.employee_name
        END,
        CASE r_c2.my_column2
        WHEN 'EMPLOYEE'      THEN r_c1.employee
        WHEN 'EMPLOYEE_NAME' THEN r_c1.employee_name
        END
      );
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

---

However, you should get rid of all the cursors and loops and do it in a single SQL statement (that will be much faster and only generate a single undo/redo log entry, compared to the loops which will be slower and will generate log entries for each loop iteration):

```sql
INSERT INTO test_table (test_column1, test_column2)
SELECT CASE m.my_column
       WHEN 'EMPLOYEE'      THEN e.employee
       WHEN 'EMPLOYEE_NAME' THEN e.employee_name
       END,
       CASE m.my_column2
       WHEN 'EMPLOYEE'      THEN e.employee
       WHEN 'EMPLOYEE_NAME' THEN e.employee_name
       END
FROM   employee e
       CROSS JOIN my_table m;
```

---

You should not need to use dynamic SQL as there should be a fixed number of columns in the `EMPLOYEE` table and if a column is added to the table then you can add it to the query at the same time.

If you absolutely must use dynamic SQL (there is not really an obvious  reason to do so) then you only need one cursor loop and then you can use `INSERT ... SELECT ...`:

```sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR c2 IS
    SELECT my_column, my_column2
    FROM   my_table;
BEGIN
  FOR r_c2 IN c2 LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO test_table (test_column1, test_column2)
                       SELECT ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(r_c2.my_column) || ', '
                                || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(r_c2.my_column2)
                      || ' FROM employee';
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2PGHFJ3w)

Comment: Thank you for solution. Though, the solution I'm looking for requires me to set the r_c1 column name based off the current r_c2 value. This is because there are too many values to map, and new values are always being added. So hard coding is not an option.

Comment: @user1781500 Surely the `EMPLOYEE` table only has a fixed number of columns and you can just white-list all of those and if you add a new column to the table then you can add a value to the query at the same time. If you cannot then you will need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, what You are trying to do. Do you want something like this?

```
create table peba_employee (employee varchar2(255), employee_name varchar2(255));
insert into peba_employee values ('a','Petr');
insert into peba_employee values ('b','David'); 

create table peba_my_table (my_column varchar2(255), my_column2 varchar2(255));
insert into peba_my_table values ('employee','employee_name');
insert into peba_my_table values ('employee_name','employee');

create table peba_test_table (test_column1 varchar2(255), test_column2 varchar2(255));

set serveroutput on
set feedback off

spool d:\somefile.sql

DECLARE
  CURSOR c2 IS  SELECT  my_column , my_column2  FROM  peba_my_table;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('declare');
  dbms_output.put_line('  CURSOR c1 IS SELECT  employee, employee_name  FROM  peba_employee;');
  dbms_output.put_line('begin');
  dbms_output.put_line('  FOR r_c1 IN c1 LOOP');

   FOR r_c2 IN c2 LOOP

     dbms_output.put_line('     INSERT INTO peba_test_table (test_column1,test_column2) values (r_c1.'||r_c2.my_column ||', r_c1.' ||r_c2.my_column2|| ');');
   END LOOP;
   
   dbms_output.put_line('  END LOOP;');
   dbms_output.put_line('END;');
   dbms_output.put_line('/');

END;
/

spool off

set feedback on

@d:\somefile.sql
```